# What is the song that plays at the end of episode 260 when Zoro senses Ship Slasher T-Bone?

Tags: one-piece, music

What is the song that plays at the end of episode 260 of *One Piece* when Zoro senses Ship Slasher T-Bone? It plays towards the end of the episode.

Comment: Hi @robertbane95, would it be possible to provide a clip?

Comment: Don't know how. Just google the episode you'll find it.

Comment: There was no song played tho, only a dark kind of music. I have no idea what song are you talking about.

Answer (score 0):

### You can listen here: [OnePieceTrackList](http://onepiecetracklist.com/Music/207.mp3)

The track is named "Suspicious Saga", track 35 from "The Cursed Holy Sword" album.